# Jax-Rs @Suspended final AsyncResponse gives internal server error 500

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, asynchronous, jax-rs

I am a beginner in Jaxrs restful asynchronous programming.

I tried different codes with  @Suspended final AsyncResponse gives internal server error 500. local Server : Websphere Liberty

Without @Suspended final AsyncResponse synchronous application is working fine. I enabled `<feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>` in server.xml.

I am using http://localhost:9080/cdiexecitemsTimeout from restclient to call the api.

My classes are as below:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.CompletionCallback;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ConnectionCallback;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;
import javax.ws.rs.container.TimeoutHandler;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("cdiexecitemsTimeout")
public class ItemsCDIExecutorResourceTimeout {

    ItemService itemService = new ItemService();

    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService executor;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void getItems(@Suspended final AsyncResponse ar) {
        System.out.println("cdiexecitems: " + executor);

        ar.setTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        ar.setTimeoutHandler(new TimeoutHandler() {
            public void handleTimeout(AsyncResponse arg0) {
                ar.resume(Response.ok("Backup plan! " + new Item().getId()).build());
            }
        });

        ar.register(new CompletionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("DONE! ");
                if ( t != null ) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        ar.register(new ConnectionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDisconnect(AsyncResponse ar) {
                System.out.println("Disconnected: " + ar);
            }
        });

        Runnable r = () -> {
            Collection<Item> result = itemService.listItems();
            Response resp = Response.ok(result).build();
            ar.resume(resp);
        };

        executor.submit(r);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ItemService {

    /**
     * "Long-running" list operation
     * @return Collection containing two items
     */
    public Collection<Item> listItems() {
        Collection<Item> result = Arrays.asList(new Item(), new Item());
        try {
            System.out.println("Wait for 30 seconds before returning " + result);
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        // The list always contains 2 items, that will have incrementing ids
        return result;
    }

    public void addItem(Item newItem) {
        System.out.println("New items added");
    }

    public Item get(int id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Item {
    private final static AtomicInteger next = new AtomicInteger();

    private long id;

    public Item() {
        id = next.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "item-"+id;
    }
```

### }

I checked that in server console there is no log is printed for the error.
When I am mentioning **"@Suspended final AsyncResponse"** even first line of **getItems()** method i.e. System.out.println() statement is not executing. It's directly showing internal server error i.e. 500 in response with below error.

### Response body is showing the below error:

```
"<error>An error occurred while processing a request.</error>"
```

### Response headers are as below:

```
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, x-auth-token, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, userid,subscr
iberid,applicationicid
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 60
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 06 Sep 2017 18:30:17 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000zgpDbKh-h8Ej7qWFwzrgqXk:5d00ad20-2db0-463a-9c76-a6ba0eb76dcc; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
```

---

Here in response header, I looked two strange things as below:

1. connection is showing closed.
2. Content-Type is showing **application/octet-stream.**
   Though I mentioned mediatype is **JSON** for below API resource method

   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void getItems(@Suspended final AsyncResponse ar)

Can you please help me out to know more the exact error.

Comment: you should have an exception on the server side, 500 is an error on the server

Comment: Yes 500 is an error on server. Synchronous api call is working fine. But for asynchronous call the debug pointer is not reaching at least first line of statement. Before reaching first line of statement it is throwing 500 error. Can you please explain why I am getting server error for only asynchronous api call from rest client / swagger / from browser url? Is there any difference between Asynchronous  jaxrs Api call and jax-rs synchronous api call from rest client / from browser / from swagger?

Comment: I mean, this is a server problem, the fault does not lie with the caller but the receiver. So, if you are the owner of the server check your logs, if you're not, then contact the server admin and ask

Comment: @DebajitRaha You able to resolve this error? As I am facing the same error.